# How to enable client-side Blazor debugging?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I remember seeing some documentation to enable client-side debugging by telling the app to switch to server-side via the query string:

> ?mode=server

But now i am not able to find any reference of this query string. I do remember adding this query string and being able to debug client-side code (meaning the client-side code was actually running on the server-side).

**Summary**
Server-side code is something i CAN debug.
Client-side code is something i am TRYING to debug.
I am running an Asp.net Hosted Blazor app.
I should've kept a bookmark of the online document to the query string :(

Please advise.

**Updated**

> I think i just found it. https://edcharbeneau.com/blazor-statehaschanged-101918/
>   However following the steps outlined in this article proves Blazor is moving fast as syntax is not quite one-to-one. In short, client-side debugging via the ?mode=server is still not working.

Comment: You may consider trying to switch client-side to server-side to enable server-side debugging. Try to refer [Make it easy to develop and debug using server-side Blazor and then switch to client-side Blazor #1318](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1318). As the Chris's answer, there is no official doc to show debugging directly from client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was never anything official, it came from the community. However, this stopped working a while back. The link you’ve found to Ed’s show is about moving all logic to a shared library and just running a client-side and server-side shell. You can then use the server-side shell to debug and the client-side one for deployment.

Currently the only way to debug client-side Blazor is via the browser debugging explained in the documentation.

Comment: This seems to be working again after updating visual studio 2019 community to the latest update.